# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I am using ASP.NET with MS.Access
In databse.. there is table called login with three fields i.e. id, username, password.
following is the code which i am trying to run.

```
String username = TextBox1.Text;
String password = TextBox2.Text;
OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source=C:\\Users\\Mohit Kumar Singla\\Documents\\phonebook.accdb");
dbConnection.Open();

Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred. Please check");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error--------------------------------");

String q = "insert into login (username, password) values (@u, @p)";               
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, dbConnection);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", password);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting this ERROR "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: Maybe escaping your table and column names like "login" "username" or "password" with square brackets? I.e. `[login]`, `[username]` and `[password]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
String q = "insert into login (username, [password]) values (@u, @p)";
```

**cause: password is reserved word**

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I changed password to "user_pass". after this, it shows Error "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: Wow, hey, great! How on earth did you come to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String username = TextBox1.Text;
String password = TextBox2.Text;
OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source=C:\\Users\\Mohit Kumar Singla\\Documents\\phonebook.accdb");
dbConnection.Open();

Console.WriteLine("Error Occurred. Please check");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error--------------------------------");

String q = "insert into login (username, [password]) values (@u, @p)";               
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, dbConnection);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", password);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbConnection.Close();
```